# Analyzing installation rates, not quite binomial. Tried bootstrapping. Is there a approximate binomial approach that would be better?

Tags: binomial-distribution, bootstrap

I'm analyzing a data set of installation rates of lighting fixture projects and want to determine the expected installation rate and the confidence interval. Projects have various numbers of fixtures intended to be installed and the most common rate is 100% followed in frequency by a handful of 0% and then a small number of rates besides 0 and 100%. The distribution of the sample data looks like this:

[image]

In many ways it seems like this data should follow a binomial distribution except for the variable number of fixtures in each project and the possibility of values other than 0 and 1.

As a result of this confusion, I simply bootstrapped the average installation rates, weighted by project size, and arrived at this distribution of results.

[image]

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better way to treat this as an approximate binomial distribution with weights for project size, or use a non-parametric approach?

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Comment: Do you correctly interprete the bootstrap distribution? Hint: it is not the distribution of the true mean rate because the latter is a constant.

Comment: You appear to have a value above 1 in your first plot. If these are not proportions, what are they?

Comment: @Glen_b: The data are the ratios of the number of fixtures installed vs those claimed in an efficiency program, so they can exceed 100% on occasions where more have been installed than originally claimed.

Comment: @MichaelMayer I'm interpreting the bootstrap results as the distribution of the statistic I've recalculated.

Comment: @GregFanslow If the numerator and denominator in the ratio don't necessarily refer to the same units, It's not clear to me why one would entertain a binomial model for the situation at all. Can you give some more details about the extent to which the two correspond / don't?

Comment: @GregFanslow: The bootstrap distribution has about the same shape as the sampling distribution, so you know the sampling error. But they have different locations in general. So I am still wondering if you draw the right conclusions from the bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an estimate of the average (arithmetic mean) and its error, the bootstrap seems reasonable to me.

But are you sure you want the arithmetic mean and its error?

Of course, it depends on your application, but for most purpose, it seems to me that you would want something else. You might want estimation of quantiles (say, 10th, median and 90th percentiles), either of the installation rate (possibly weighted, possibly not); or you might want to go straight to "number of fixtures" to be installed.

Comment: We need an installation rate estimate that we can apply to a larger program, so I'd like the mean and confidence interval.<br><br>

With the need to do weighting and the few strange values, Bootstrapping was all I could think of doing. But I just wanted to put it to the larger community, since it seems like an issue that would come up on occasion.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say "median" where I said "mean" above, so I've been doing what you suggest.<br/><br/>

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have seen things saying that bootstrapping quantiles is the best way to get their SE, but I don't remember where I saw this

Comment: Since the bootstrap results are an estimate of the actual distribution of the statistic wouldn't the SE just be 84.1%-ile minus the median? Perhaps not very rigorous, but intuitively this is how I think about it.